# Usage of "eggheads and fatheads" in a sentence

Tags: expressions

Recently I came across this expression "*eggheads and fatheads*". 
I know the individual meanings of both the words. In which context should I use these two words together?

Comment: You can use them **together** whenever there's a situation involving these two types of individuals (there could be overlap).

Comment: Any involving both :-)

Comment: yes Russell ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Egghead](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egghead) *(an intellectual; highbrow)* and [fathead](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fathead) *(a stupid person; fool)* are informal idiomatic usages with almost diametrically opposite meanings.

But it's important to note that the "metaphorical" element in both terms is somewhat obscure. The first alludes to a popular stereotype of intellectuals having high foreheads (hence *highbrow*). The second draws on the various negative connotations of *fat, gross, thick, dense* implying *stupid*.

Using both words in close proximity inevitably draws attention to the fact that there's no obvious opposition/contrast between *egg* and *fat* except when conjoined with *head*. It's my opinion that this constitutes a noticeable "disjunct", so I would advise against doing it *unless you want the quirky juxtaposition for stylistic reasons*.